# Вопрос о правильном произношении Благодарения

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

По моему разумению, когда благодарят, обращаясь к одариваемому, нужно произносить: «Благодарю тебе».
Но не «Благодарю тебя», так как, в этом случае, мы обращаемся к благу, — мы его дарим.
Прав ли я?
Если нет, то почему?

Comment: Хотите одарить кого-то, пишите раздельно. «Благо дарю тебе» или «Дарю тебе благо».  Если  обращаетесь к «благу», что несколько странно, но всё может быть, то « Благо, дарю тебя».

Answer (score 2):

Нет, вы не правы. Вот что говорят словари.
[дарить](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

1. [давать в качестве подарка; отдавать безвозмездно] **кому что**. *У черкесов есть очень милый обычай дарить гостю всё, что он похвалит* (Купр.); *Девушки с весёлыми, смеющимися лицами дарили танкистам цветы* (Баб.).
2. [одаривать; удостаивать какими-либо знаками внимания] **кого чем**. *Длинный список его славных друзей заканчивается такими именами, как Пирогов, Кавелин и поэт Некрасов, дарившими его самой искренней и тёплой дружбой* (Ч.).

[благодарить](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Blagodarit-21883.html)
**кого-что**. Выражать благодарность. *Благодарить друзей. Благодарить судьбу. Благодарить за помощь, за оказанную честь. Сердечно, от всей души благодарю.* Благодарить от имени кого-либо, чего-либо (офиц.). Благодарить словами, пожатием руки. **Благодарю вас** (вежливая форма выражения благодарности; спасибо).

Вот что разъясняет "Грамота".
Прежде всего необходимо отметить, что слово *благодарить* не было образовано в живой русской речи посредством сложения слов *благо* и *дарить* (утверждение «когда-то люди говорили друг другу: "благо дарю вам", а потом это превратилось в *благодарю*» неверно).
В. В. Виноградов указывает, что ***благодарить* — калькированный по греческому образцу славянизм** (ср.: *благоговеть, благоволить* и др.), другими словами, это слово книжное, искусственное (калька — это перевод по частям иноязычного слова или оборота речи).
Управление *благодарить кого-либо* могло возникнуть под влиянием управления *дарить кого-либо*. Глагол *дарить* управляет дательным падежом (*дарить кому*) в значении «давать в качестве подарка»; в значении же «одаривать, удостаивать какими-либо знаками внимания» дарить управляет винительным падежом (*дарить кого*) — это устаревшая, книжная форма: *Веселая девушка ласково улыбалась ему, иногда дарила его парой незначительных слов* (М. Горький).

Уже в XVIII веке наблюдались колебания в управлении *благодарить кого / благодарить кому.*
В «Словаре русского языка» XVIII века (Выпуск 2. Л.: Наука, 1985) находим примеры: *Кто тебя наказует, тому благодари и почитаи его за такова, которои тебе всякого добра желает* (Юности честное зерцало, 1717). *Наемной лакей всегда благодарил меня, когда я давал ему в день полтину* (Н. Карамзин, Письма русского путешественника, 1791–1792). Также: *[Прямиков]: Чувствительно тебя благодарю, мой друг!* (В. Капнист, Ябеда, 1794–1798).
Таким образом, к концу XVIII века устоялся вариант *благодарить кого-либо.*

[Почему мы говорим *спасибо Вам* и *благодарю Вас*...](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords?layout=item&id=25_404)